# What does "@" and "=" mean in the angularJS scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The codes can be viewed at https://github.com/darylrowland/angucomplete/blob/master/angucomplete.js

A snippet looks like this:

```
angular.module('angucomplete', [] )
    .directive('angucomplete', function ($parse, $http, $sce, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            "id": "@id",
            "placeholder": "@placeholder",
            "selectedObject": "=selectedobject",
            "url": "@url",
            "dataField": "@datafield",
            "titleField": "@titlefield",
            "descriptionField": "@descriptionfield",
            "imageField": "@imagefield",
            "imageUri": "@imageuri",
            "inputClass": "@inputclass",
            "userPause": "@pause",
            "localData": "=localdata",
            "searchFields": "@searchfields",
            "minLengthUser": "@minlength",
            "matchClass": "@matchclass"
        },
```

What I can't understand is the magic `@` and `=` string. Is it a special char in AngularJS?(I'm not sure because search a sign in google is hard..) If so, what is its usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While creating a directive in angularjs these two special characters are used very often `@` and `=`.

## Usage of `@` in angularjs directive

```
app.directive("directive1",function(){
return{
    restrict:"E",
    template:"<p></p>",
    scope:{
      text:"@text"
    }
};
});

<directive1 text="Usage of @ in angularjs directive"></directive1>
```

Here any changes to the parent scope text will change the local scope text, but not the other way around.

## Usage of `=` in angularjs directive

```
app.directive("directive1",function(){
return{
    restrict:"E",
    template:"<p></p>",
    scope:{
      text:"=text"
    }
};
});

<directive1 text="Usage of = in angularjs directive"></directive1>
```

Here any changes to the parent scope text will change the local scope text, as wel as the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great article by Dan Wahlin about the Angular Isolated scope system, you can have a read here: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope

Answer (score 1):

These are indeed special characters in AngularJS.

The official documentation is pretty hard to find it is defined under the `$compile`-service documentation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-